# UART access on windows10 for RaspberryPi

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, windowsondevices

After looking through the documentation avaliable on the ms-iot website (http://ms-iot.github.io/content/win10/StartCoding.htm) there seems to be no referance to access the UART on either the RasberryPi or the MinnowBoard Max. When looking at the Pinout for these devices you can see that the Tx/Rx pins are labled as reserved (http://ms-iot.github.io/content/win10/samples/PinMappingsRPi2.htm).

Does anyone know how to access the serial port (or have a suggestion on where to start looking) as im looking to use rs485 and would rather have to use a MAX3140 on either the RasberryPi or the MinnowBoard Max.

Thank You

George Stephens

Comment: You have two problems.  Google "usb to rs485 converter".